# Node.js API architecture best practice: controller vs service

Tags: node.js, api, architecture

If I understood correctly, according to the principle of separation of concerns, it is considered best practice to move the business logic away from the controller and into the service layer.

Is this always the case though?

For instance, when facing very short statements such as:

```
const myModelInstance = await TheModel.findbypk(1);
```

should one move this line to a separate `getModelInstanceByPk` file for instance, or could it just be left as is inside the controller?

Answer (score 0):

As you will move toward big queries and you will have to join data from documents, then you will feel ease if you separate them from now...
and its good to keep separate files for separate type of code dealing